# $watchcollection doesn't work on model property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-watch

I'm using $watchcollection for to observe the my model upon changes. i initialized my model like this

```
$scope.feature = {
        additional: [],
        collision: 0,
        baseTotal: 0
    }
```

i use `$watchcollection` to check model changes

```
$scope.$watchCollection('feature', function (val) {
    var addtional = 0;
    angular.forEach(val.additional, function (e, t) {
        addtional += parseFloat(e.value.toFixed(2));
    });
},true);
```

Problem is, this not getting fired when only update `feature.additional`.
  Does anybody have any work around or please let me know if something is wrong.

Comment: I can't quite find the post at the moment, but the reason is that collection doesn't watch deep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
$scope.$watch('feature', function (newVal, oldVal) {
  var addtional = 0;
  angular.forEach(newVal.additional, function (e, t) {
    addtional += parseFloat(e.value.toFixed(2));
  });
}, true);
```

Comment: that did!! thanks mate. do you know the reason why `$watch` works instead of `$watchcollection` ?

Comment: $watchCollection watches the properties of an object. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope